# How to display a dropdown menu based on cursor position using javascript or react?

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming and want to check if the string contains `@` character before or after the cursor position.

If the `@` is present only before cursor position in the input field then get the complete string after `@`.

If the `@` is present before and after the cursor position then get the string from `@` (that is the one before cursor position) until white space.

String example: `"I am @u @user1"`, here cursor position is at index 8.

What I have tried: I am using `event.target.selectionStart` to get the cursor position and then the `lastindexOf('@')` in the string.

```
if (event.target.selectionStart > event.target.value.lastIndexOf('@')) {
    /*this means there is no @ after cursor position*/
    string =    event.target.value.substr(event.target.value.lastIndexOf('@') +1);
}
```

But I am not sure how to find out if there is another `@` character before cursor position and how to get the string after `@` that is before the cursor position.

I am quite confused and don't know how to proceed further. Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you're on the right track.

You just have to be more specific in your conditionnals.

```js
const test = document.querySelector('input');

test.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {

  if (event.target.selectionStart > event.target.value.indexOf('@') && event.target.selectionStart > event.target.value.lastIndexOf('@')) {
    console.log(event.target.value.substring(event.target.value.indexOf('@')));
  }
  if (event.target.selectionStart <= event.target.value.indexOf('@') && event.target.selectionStart <= event.target.value.lastIndexOf('@')) {
    console.log('after cursor');
  }
  if (event.target.selectionStart > event.target.value.indexOf('@') && event.target.selectionStart <= event.target.value.lastIndexOf('@')) {
    console.log(event.target.value.substring(event.target.value.indexOf('@'), event.target.value.lastIndexOf('@')));
  }
})
```

```html
<input value="I am @u @user1">
```